# Editing brackets in TeX-studio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, brackets

I use TeX Studio and I often start to write mathematical formulae without bothering to put `\left` or whatever formatting I need for the bracket. The I go back looking at the formula and edit accordingly.

In TeX Studio, is there a shortcut/command to edit the right bracket automatically when I edit the left bracket? That would be extremely handy for speed of typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality built in. However, you could implement this yourself using a [macro](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33).

Comment: Could you please have a look at https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1863/ ?